# StepExecutionListener is missing onErrorInStep() method in Spring Batch 2.2.7

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am migrating from Spring Batch 1.1.4 to Spring Batch 2.2.7 and I have a [`StepExecutionListener`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/1.1.x/apidocs/index.html?org/springframework/batch/core/step/item/SkipLimitStepFactoryBean.html) implementation which has `onErrorInStep` implemented. This method was no longer available in [`StepExecutionListener`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/2.2.x/apidocs/index.html?org/springframework/batch/core/step/factory/FaultTolerantStepFactoryBean.html) of Spring Batch 2.2.7.

Do I need to use any other interface/classes instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also very well manage exceptions from `StepExecutionListener's afterStep()` method as as shown below:

```
ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution)
{
List exceptions = stepExecution.getFailureExceptions();
.......
}
```